# How can I link multiple tables in MySQL database other than using primary key-foreign key relation?

Tags: mysql, database

I have tables named 'studentdetails', 'class', 'obtainedmarks',  and 'subject' in a database.
I have a primary key named 'STUDENTID' in table 'studentdetails' which is connected to other tables as a foreign key.

I want to make one more primary key in the same table 'studentdetails' taking three columns ('STUDENTID','CLASS','ROLLNO') so that I can use the foreign key relation to the three columns of 'obtainedmarks' table.

How can I establish such relation as we can make only one primary key in a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql certainly allows foreign key relationships to span multiple columns. In fact there is even a full example in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). Thus your relationship might look something like

```
 CONSTRAINT fk_multi FOREIGN KEY (`studentid`, `class`,`subject`)
 REFERENCES other_table (`studentid`, `class`,`subject`)
 ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
```

Note however that what goes into the REFERENCES section is the names of the columns and not the name of the index on that other table.

Getting onto the Primary Key problem, it's true that you can only have one primary key per table. But there's nothing to prevent you from creating a composite unique key on the three columns that are referenced.

Comment: That is a very helpful reference @e4c5
Now I know that primary key is not compulsory need for the foreign key.

Comment: Glad to have been of help